# Python - simple NumPy array not showing expected values

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Python newbie here.

I think I have written some pretty straightforward code to extract ONLY the numbers from a received string.

It appears to be working EXCEPT I am trying to store the retrieved numbers in a NumPy array for further processing but I am seeing only 'wacky' numbers instead.

```
import numpy as np
#import array
apiString = " 'open': 1.082865 'close': 1.08287 'min': 1.08266 'max': 1.08295 'volume': 888"
np_Myarr01 = np.empty([1,5], dtype=float)

def Find_numbers():
    for word in apiString.split():
        try:
            thisNumber=float(word)
            print ("Found", thisNumber)
            Store_number(thisNumber)
        except ValueError:
            pass
    return

def Store_number(thisNumber):
    np.append(np_Myarr01, thisNumber)
    print("store " + str(thisNumber))
    return


# START OF MAIN PROGRAM

Find_numbers()
print (np_Myarr01)
```

*** OUTPUT *******************

```
Found 1.082865
store 1.082865
Found 1.08287
store 1.08287
Found 1.08266
store 1.08266
Found 1.08295
store 1.08295
Found 888.0
store 888.0
[[  2.17306514e-316   0.00000000e+000   6.92674292e-310   6.92674292e-310
    2.37151510e-322]]
```

---

I was HOPING for the array to read

```
[[ 1.082865  1.08287  1.08266  1.08295  888.0]]
```

Any help would be gratefully appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: `numpy.append()` doesn't modify the array in place, it appends to a copy and returns it.

Comment: The wacky numbers are the original contents of the array, since `np.empty()` doesn't initialize them.

Comment: It seems like you should be using a list, and then convert it to an array at the end.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a mixture of `str.split()` and `re.search` to extract the numbers from your `apiString`:

This:

```
apiString = " 'open': 1.082865 'close': 1.08287 'min': 1.08266 'max': 1.08295 'volume': 888"

my_array = np.array([float(x) for x in apiString.split() if not re.search('[a-zA-Z]', x)])
```

Will yield:

```
array([  1.082865,   1.08287 ,   1.08266 ,   1.08295 , 888.      ])
```

Details:

1)  `apiString.split()` will split your string in a list of strings where there are spaces in the original string

2) `re.search('[a-zA-Z]', x)` will return `True` if the string stored in `x` contains an uppercase or lowercase letter (i.e. not a number) (also why we use `not` here)

3) `float(x)` converts the string `'1.808'` to type float

Answer (score -1):

In addition to @barmar's comments, if your API string always looks as shown in the example, you can extract every other item after splitting (with slicing), and let NumPy handle the rest of conversion:

```
np_Myarr01 = np.fromiter(apiString.split()[1::2], float)
```